# Display iframe of site on hover with html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to display a site in an iframe while hovering over the link preferably just using html/css. I've tried something like:

```
onmouseover="<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work.

How could I hover over a link and display the site's iframe? How could I do this for multiple links?

Thank you

Comment: You could add the iframe in a container and hide the container using JS or CSS and simply toggle the visibility of respective iframe on hover

Comment: Hey there Logan, and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your attempt seems a bit *weak* in this context. You'll likely have to use CSS `:hover` or perhaps JavaScript hiding/showing. Consider doing some research into these specific categories and providing a slightly more robust attempt that we can help debug. As it stands, for us to answer your question, we'd essentially be writing the entirety of the code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to place the iframe within the link, styled to be hidden. You'd then use a CSS selector to display it when you hover on the link.

CSS file:

```
.iframe-link iframe {
    display: none;
}
.iframe-link:hover iframe {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="iframe-link" href="https://www.google.com">Link text<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe></a>
```